# Create filtered request to wms/wfs openlayers 3

Tags: filter, openlayers, wms, openlayers-3

I need to create a filtered WMS request to Geoserver. I am rewriting an openlayers 2 application which make these requests using OpenLayers.Filter. How can this be done in Openlayers 3 where the Filters are removed from the API?

Here is an example how the query is in Openlayers 2:

```
function dateFilter(date) {
    var dateTimeFilterArray = [];

    var dateFilter = new OL.Filter.Comparison({
        type : OL.Filter.Comparison.BETWEEN,
        property : "stdate",
        lowerBoundary : date.fromDate,
        upperBoundary : date.toDate
    });

    dateTimeFilterArray.push(dateFilter);

    var timeFilter = new OL.Filter.Comparison({
        type : OL.Filter.Comparison.BETWEEN,
        property : "sttime",
        lowerBoundary : date.fromTime,
        upperBoundary : date.toTime
    });

    dateTimeFilterArray.push(timeFilter);

    return combineFilters(dateTimeFilterArray);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For WMS requests to GeoServer, you can use CQL filters, e.g.

```
function dateFilter(date) {
  var dateFilter =
      'stdate BETWEEN ' + date.fromDate + ' AND ' + date.toDate;
  var timeFilter =
      'sttime BETWEEN ' + date.fromTime + ' AND ' + date.toTime;
  return '(' + dateFilter + ') AND (' timeFilter + ')';
}

wmsSource.updateParams({
  CQL_FILTER: dateFilter(date)
});
```

Please read up on date and time literals in the [ECQL reference](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/filter/ecql_reference.html) to make sure you use the correct date and time format for the CQL filter. My snippet above assumes that the properties of your `date` object are in the correct format already. It also assumes that your current `combineFilters()` function combines the filters using logical `AND`.

Comment: Thanks for descriptive answer. This consept works fine!

Comment: Hi @ahocevar is there a way to later delete that `CQL_FILTER`?